# Response body empty using Retrofit2

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, response

So I've tried the request in Postman and it works fine. But when I do it in Android the response.body() is empty. The request sends an email and password for login and should return User object with other details.

```
loginUser.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   loginView.onLoginResult(response.body());
                } else {
                    loginView.showLoginErrorResult();
                }
            }
```

Here is my Retrofit interface:

```
public interface NetworkAPI {

   @POST("/login")
   Call<User> login(@Body UserLogin userLogin);
}
```

RetrofitClient:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getAPI(String BASE_URL) {


    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

My User class:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("firstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

public User(String id, String token, String email, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.token = token;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
   //getters &setters...
}
```

Postman request:

```
{
    "email":"test@email.com",
    "password":"123456"
}
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "payload": {
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
    }
}
```

Also i'm getting a 200 response but no data on body

Comment: Please [edit] and post Retrofit interface class, sample URL and Postman client screenshots.

Comment: Share your User class and Json Response from Postman..

Comment: @IntsabHaider i've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a New Model like this

```
public class ResponseApi{
        boolean success;
        User payload;

        public boolean isSuccess() {
            return success;
        }

        public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
            this.success = success;
        }

        public User getPayload() {
            return payload;
        }

        public void setPayload(User payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }

    }
```

And then change your code like this

```
public interface NetworkAPI {

   @POST("users/login")
   Call< ResponseApi > login(@Body UserLogin userLogin);
}
```

Hope it will work.. Actually Retrofit unable to parse your json object due to different Structure.

Comment: Call< ResponseApi > login(@Body UserLogin userLogin); after changing this you have to change it from where its override or implemented..